# cut / cut down * cut down on

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

I never know when to use "cut down on", "cut down" or just "cut". Some sentences I've come across:

- *They are trying to cut street crime in the area.*
  [Would "cut down on street crime" be ok?]
- *You should cut down on your drinking.*
  [Why not "cut (down) your drinking"?]
- *Installing double-glazing will cut down the noise from traffic.*
  [cut the noise? cut down on the noise?]

Do you think using always "cut" would be a safe choice? Or even better, could you come up with some kind of rule?

Answer (score 1):

With some verbs the distinction is easy to see, e.g.

**Part 1**

*Don't pick me.*  versus *Don't pick on me."*

1. The use of 'on' turns 'me' from a direct object into an indirect object.
2. 'on' in this context means 'with respect to'

So -

*Don't pick me.* means *Don't choose me.*

*Don't pick on me.* means *Don't pick/choose (a fight) with respect to me.*

**Part 2**

*You should cut your drinking* means literally *You should remove your drinking (from your life)*

*You should cut down your drinking* means *You should reduce the size/quantity of your drinking.*

*You should cut down on your drinking* means *You should make a reduction with respect to your drinking*

**Part 3**

I hope you can see that using 'on' allows us to remove the direct object from  a sentence containing a verb that requires one (i.e. a transitive verb), and substitute an indirect object. We unconsciously accept that the direct object is there without needing to know precisely what it is. In my examples, I added 'fight' and 'reduction' but someone else might have picked slightly different words with a similar meaning.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Cut* is one of those verbs that has a lot of different phrasal varieties, which can make it confusing (cut off, cut through, cut over, cut away, etc.) But I think this also makes the possible usage of *cut* by itself much more limited. In the case of both *cut down* and *cut down on*, they have very specific meanings, and I would rarely if ever use *cut* by itself to express the same idea:

- *Cut down* is most often used in reference to trees, as in *he cut down the tree*, meaning he sawed or hacked all the way through the trunk so as to make it fall. Rarely it's used as a synonym for being killed by gunfire, as in *he was cut down by an assassin*.
- *Cut down on*, on the other hand, has the sole meaning of "to reduce, use less of." In your example of *cut down the noise*, I would be tempted to say that *cut down **on** the noise* is more idiomatic. I've usually heard it used in the context of dieting, as in *he cut down on his fat intake*. You could also say *he cut down his fat intake*, but again I think adding the *on* would eliminate any confusion.

So, in summary:

1. Don't use *cut* by itself if there is a more appropriate phrasal verb.
2. If saying *cut down on* makes sense, then use that instead of *cut down*.